# Always recording ntbtlog.txt; archiving old ones

Tags: windows-vista, freeze

A friend's Vista Home Premium occasionally hangs on boot (the progress bar runs and runs for hours, but won't boot). I know that if I hit F8 during boot, I can enable boot logging in ntntlog.txt, but this only works for that boot. It's no help if you can't duplicate the hang because it occurs ingrequently on someelse's laptop.

So I want to set up Vista to always record ntbtlog.txt and archive the old ones, so I can diagnose the hang after it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> System Configuration -> Boot Tab -> Select Boot Log option.

This should keep appending all boot log data to %systemroot%\ntbtlog.txt - It should not overwrite older log data, all new entries should be appended on every boot.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer!